# Displaying values for non-existent column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

In Oracle, I can define a value for a column that doesn't exist in a table, like

```
SELECT 
    C.CUSTOMER_ID, ' ' CUSTOMER_PHONE , 'JAMAICAN' CUSTOMER_NATIONALITY.
```

I need to know if I can achieve the same in SQL Server.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)): just a starting point for the people here that want to help you. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking. Also - you can make the code parts of your question look nice by enclosing it in backticks (`), which I have proposed in your edit also.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, very similar...

```
SELECT 
    C.CUSTOMER_ID, 
    ,CUSTOMER_PHONE = ' ' 
    ,CUSTOMER_NATIONALITY = 'JAMAICAN' 
FROM
   YourTable
```

You will also see this column aliasing with the word `AS`.

```
SELECT 
    C.CUSTOMER_ID, 
    ,' ' AS CUSTOMER_PHONE  
    ,'JAMAICAN' AS CUSTOMER_NATIONALITY  
FROM
   YourTable
```

Comment: The use of the word `as` is standard SQL functionality and works in any database, including Oracle.

Comment: That’s good to know. I knew it was optional in SQL server but was not aware of this in Oracle

Comment: that's optional in Oracle, too.